# Creating JSON from fields within a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to create a JSON from all the fields that I have inside a DIV.
The script is taking all the field names and values and put them in JSON, which works fine, except for textarea. For some reason the script is missing a comma after the value of the textarea, although it should place a comma.

Here is the script and also a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/largan/j1yze8uq/23/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
                var json = buildRequestStringData($('#holder'));
        $('#result').html(json);
            }); 


function buildRequestStringData(div)
            {
                var select = div.find('select'),
                textarea = div.find('textarea'),
                input = div.find('input'),
                requestString = '{';
                for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
                    requestString += '"' + $(select[i]).attr('id') + '": "' +$(select[i]).val() + '",';
                }
                if (select.length > 0) {
                    requestString = requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1);
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
                    requestString += '"' + $(textarea[i]).attr('id') + '": "' +$(textarea[i]).val() + '",';
                }
                if (textarea.length > 0) {
                    requestString = requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1);
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                    if ($(input[i]).attr('type') !== 'checkbox') {
                        requestString += '"' + $(input[i]).attr('id') + '":"' + $(input[i]).val() + '",';
                    } else {
                        if ($(input[i]).attr('checked')) {
                            requestString += '"' + $(input[i]).attr('id') +'":"' + $(input[i]).val() +'",';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (input.length > 0) {
                    requestString = requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1);
                }
                requestString += '}';
                return requestString;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="holder">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="active">Field One</label>
<input type="text"class="form-control"  id="Field One">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="active">Field Two</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Field Two">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="active">Textarea Field</label>
<textarea class="form-control h-25" id="Textarea Field"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="active">Field Four</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Field Four">
</div>
<button class="add">
Create
</button>
</div><div class="col-md-4">
 <div id="result">

</div> 
  
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, why you need to do this `requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1)` ? why not use `$.trim(requestString)` ? if you just need to delete whitespaces . check [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) for more details .

Comment: @Swati, using `$.trim(requestString)`, did it, but still dont know why it `requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1)` works for the other fields and not for texarea

Comment: because this line `requestString.substring(0, requestString.length - 1)` is deleting  `,` . You can check if you have only 1 field i.e : only 1 textarea or 1 input you will see same result . One more question why you are generating json like this why not simply use `{}` and push data in json object?

Comment: No particular reason. I guess as I am new to jQuery, and that way looked easier. Will be nice to see another way. Guess will be nice for other people that might end up here. :)

Comment: Hi, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r832mb4a/) you can try :) .

Comment: @Swati, thanks. Looks a bit simple.